# How to do an aside with 100% height?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have this code, and I would like to have the `aside` with 100% height. I have already set the height of the `aside`, `body` and `section` to 100%, but it does not work. Do you know how to do it? Is there any other way to do it? Thanks

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'kinder';
  src: url('kindergarten.ttf');
}


/* Eléments principaux de la page */

body {
  background: url('back.jpg');
  font-family: 'kinder', Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #181818;
}

#bloc_page {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}


/* Header */

header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

#titre {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

#titre div {
  position: absolute;
  right: 40px;
  top: 25px;
}


/* Body */

aside {
  width: 5%;
  background: url(ban.jpg);
  border-radius: 4px;
}

section {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="bloc_page">
    <header>
      <div id="titre">
        <h1>Jules Raymond</h1>

        <div>
          <a href="moi.jpeg"> <img src="moi_mini.jpg" alt="Une photo de Jules Raymond" title="Cliquez pour agrandir" /></a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <h3>Etudiant à l'université de Californie-Berkeley</h3>
    </header>


    <section>
      <aside>
      </aside>

      <article id="experience">
        <h3>Mon expérience</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>De 1992 à 2004: naissance et école primaire</li>
          <li>De 2004 à 2010: école secondaire (high scool)</li>
          <li>De 2010 jusqu'à présent: étudiant universitaire</li>
        </ul>
        <article>

          <article id="competences">
            <h3>Mes compétances</h3>
            <ol>
              <li>HTML & CSS (en procès)</li>
              <li>PHP & MySql (avancé)</li>
              <li>C (expert)</li>
            </ol>
          </article>

          <article id="formation">
            <h3>Ma formation</h3>
            <ul>
              <li>J'ai appris sur <a href="http://openclassrooms.com/" title="Cliquez pour découvrir!">OpenClassroom</a>.</li>
              <li>J'ai posé mes questions sur <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/" title="Cliquez pour découvrir encore!">StackOverFlow</a>.</li>
            </ul>
          </article>
    </section>

  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: *I have already set the height of the `aside`, `body` and `section` to 100%...* That's not reflected in your code. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this below css code with "max-height:100%;"

```
<style type="text/css">
    @font-face {
     font-family: 'kinder';
     src: url('kindergarten.ttf');
    }

    /* Eléments principaux de la page */
    body
    {
        background: url('back.jpg');
        font-family: 'kinder', Arial, sans-serif;
        color: #181818;
    }

    #bloc_page
    {
        width: 100%;
        margin: auto;
    }

    /* Header */
    header
    {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction:column;
        justify-content:space-between;
        align-items:center;
    }

    #titre
    {
        display:flex;
        flex-direction:row;
        align-items:flex-end;
    }

    #titre div
    {
        position:absolute;
        right: 40px;
        top: 25px;
    }

    /* Body */
    aside
    {
        width: 5%;
        max-height:100%;
        background: url(ban.jpg);
        border-radius: 4px;
        word-wrap:break-word;
        border:1px solid red;
    }

    section
    {
        display:flex;
    }

    </style>
    <body>
        <div id="bloc_page">
            <header>
                <div id="titre">
                    <h1>Jules Raymond</h1>

                    <div> 
                        <a href="moi.jpeg"> <img src="moi_mini.jpg" alt="Une photo de Jules Raymond" title="Cliquez pour agrandir" /></a> 
                    </div>
                </div>

                <h3>Etudiant à l'université de Californie-Berkeley</h3>
            </header>


            <section>
                <aside>this is testing</aside>

                <article id="experience">
                    <h3>Mon expérience</h3>
                        <ul>
                            <li>De 1992 à 2004: naissance et école primaire</li>
                            <li>De 2004 à 2010: école secondaire (high scool)</li>
                            <li>De 2010 jusqu'à présent: étudiant universitaire</li>
                        </ul>
                <article>

                <article id="competences">
                    <h3>Mes compétances</h3>
                        <ol>
                            <li>HTML & CSS (en procès)</li>
                            <li>PHP & MySql (avancé)</li>
                            <li>C (expert)</li>
                        </ol>
                </article>

                <article id="formation">
                    <h3>Ma formation</h3>
                        <ul>
                            <li>J'ai appris sur <a href="http://openclassrooms.com/" title="Cliquez pour découvrir!">OpenClassroom</a>.</li>
                            <li>J'ai posé mes questions sur <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/" title="Cliquez pour découvrir encore!">StackOverFlow</a>.</li>
                        </ul>
                </article>
            </section>

        </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the position of your aside tag to absolute, then change the height and the width to whatever you want or need. (note i made the background red to make it clear that the height changed)

jsfiddle,net/thpgq299